# value 1- cannot be converted to a number

Tags: coldfusion

I am using the following stuff to for data conversion:

```
<cfset Year = Left(mbTimeStamp_dt,4)>
<cfset Month = mid(mbTimeStamp_dt,5,2)>
<cfset Date = mid(mbTimeStamp_dt,7,2)>
<cfset Hour = mid(mbTimeStamp_dt,9,2)>
<cfset Minute = right(mbTimeStamp_dt,2)>
<cfset NewDate= "#Createdatetime(Year,Month,Date,Hour,Minute,00)#">

<cfset PSTTime = #DateConvert("UTC2Local", NewDate )# >
<cfset ESTTime = DateAdd('h',3,PSTTime)>
```

But I am getting an error on the following line:

```
<cfset NewDate= "#Createdatetime(Year,Month,Date,Hour,Minute,00)#">
```

> Error message: "The value 1- cannot be converted to a number. "

Am I doing something wrong? For your reference, my `mbTimestamp_dt` value looks like this:

```
      2013-06-06 11:51:37
```

Comment: basic debugging.  cfdump all the year/month/date/hour?

Comment: Agree with Henry. How is it it didn't occur to you to actually CHECK the values of your variables. Your logic is wrong for most of your date parts.

Comment: I'd also highly suggest renaming your variables so they don't cause confusion with the built-in functions of the same name.

Comment: *CHECK the values of your variables* +100. Verifying your assumptions are correct, by outputting the actual values, should always be the first step in debugging this kind of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your string parsing functions, save for year, are returning incorrect values. As others have said, output those values before trying to do anything with them and you'll see what's wrong.

On a side note. Rather than parsing the string manually, you could use some of the built in ColdFusion date/time functions to fetch your relevant values.

```
<cfset Year = Year(mbTimeStamp_dt)>
<cfset Month = Month(mbTimeStamp_dt)>
<cfset Day = Day(mbTimeStamp_dt)>
<cfset Hour = Hour(mbTimeStamp_dt)>
<cfset Minute = Minute(mbTimeStamp_dt)>

<cfset NewDate = createDateTime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, 00)>
<cfset PSTTime = dateConvert("UTC2Local", NewDate)>
<cfset ESTTime = dateAdd('h', 3, PSTTime)>
```

I changed your variable `Date` to `Day` to avoid ambiguity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: *use some of the built in ColdFusion date/time functions* But that essentially makes the `createDateTime` statement redundant ;-) Those functions must implicitly convert the input string to a date object in order to extract the relevant parts (month,day, etc...). If it can do that already, you may as well skip the first six lines and just use `parseDateTime`. (Of course you lose the ability to pre-validate like with strings, but validation is a separate issue ...)

Comment: @Leigh I thought it was redundant as well, but for the zeroing of the second value in the resulting NewDate variable. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AveryMartell - No, you are correct about zeroing out the seconds. But there are simpler ways to do that, like a simple `dateAdd`

Answer (score 0):

Output every one of those variables.  The one with a hyphen in it is the one causing the problem.  Then look at your string functions.

Make sure you test the month, date, hour, and minute functions with timestamps that give both 1 and 2 digit numbers.

**Edit**

Not related to your question, but you are assigning the seconds from your timestamp string to the Minute variable.